# saving an svg object onto disk

Tags: r, svg

I am working with a function that outputs an svg object. As I see the SVG object is essentially a string of characters.
I was wondering how to 
1) plot the svg output from the function
2) save this svg object to disk under an svg extension? I tried ggsave but just resulted in an error.

I am fairly new to svg handling, so would appreciate any inputs.
Thanks!

Comment: This package could be of help https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svglite/svglite.pdf

Comment: What error did you get exactly? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I tried that for a package I was developing and it was not straightforward. In the end, I needed two libraries: `rsvg` and `grImport2`. Here is the code I used:

```
  tfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".svg")
  tfile2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
  cat(svg_code, file=tfile)
  if (requireNamespace("rsvg", quietly = TRUE) && requireNamespace("grImport2", quietly = TRUE)) {
    rsvg::rsvg_svg(svg = tfile, tfile2)
    p <- grImport2::readPicture(tfile2)
    grImport2::grid.picture(p)
  } else {
    if (systemShow == FALSE && outFile == ''){
      warning("The figure cannot be rendered in the plot window. Please, use the arguments outFile and/or systemShow.")
    }
  }
  if (systemShow){
    utils::browseURL(tfile)
  }
```

The first conditional is in case the system does not allow the installation of either package. As you can see, you first need to write the svg code (`svg_code`) to a file, in this case temporary (`tfile`). Then, `rsvg_svg` writes a temporary png file (`tfile2`). Finally, `grImport2::readPicture` and `grImport2::grid.picture` show the converted file in the plot window. I also left the part where the user can set a boolean variable (`systemShow`) and the package will attempt to open the file on the default system svg viewer.

2) That one is much easier. You just need to write the code to a file as text, like `cat(svg_code, file='path_to_file.svg')`.